# Adding 3 foreign key in mysql, reported 'missing closing parentasis'

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

My code is as below. There is a problem with the first foreign key, visit_items_fk.

SQL report 'missing closing parentasis' on the second variable.
e.g. sch_name when I place any of the 3 at the 2nd variable in (visit_date, sch_name, lib_name).

However, when I remove one variable and become like (visit_date, sch_name), there is no error reported. Thanks!

```
create table visit_items
(lib_name      varchar(50)    not null,
sch_name       varchar(50)    not null,
visit_date     date           not null,
item_id        varchar(25)    not null,
constraint visit_items_fk foreign key (visit_date, sch_name, lib_name) references school_visit (visit_date, sch_name, lib_name),
constraint visit_items_fk1 foreign key (item_id) references item (item_id),
constraint visit_items_pk primary key (lib_name, sch_name, visit_date, item_id));


create table school_visit
(lib_name      varchar(50)    not null,
sch_name       varchar(50)    not null,
visit_date     date           not null,
theme          varchar(100)   not null,
constraint school_visit_pk primary key (lib_name, sch_name, visit_date),
constraint school_visit_fk foreign key (lib_name) references library (lib_name),
constraint school_visit_fk1 foreign key (sch_name) references school (sch_name));
```

Comment: You're referencing a table called school_visit, does table school_visit have a column named lib_name?

Comment: Please add to your post and show your tables and their columns so we have more to go on than just your create table query.

Comment: @RyanWilson sure thank you